# Working with the MIT-SHM X11 extension on Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, remote-desktop

I am trying to get Blender to work over a setup where Blender itself runs on a remote machine and its UI is presented to a local machine via X11.

Detailed information about that is available [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147699/blender-on-remote-linux-machine-via-x-server/147700#147700).

This seems to be a frequently required use case and Blender itself will work, through the `blender-softwaregl` executable that is provided along the zip archive download option from [blender.org](https://www.blender.org/) but only up to version 2.79.

On version 2.80, the same executable seems to be trying to setup a shared memory "object" which requires the MIT-SHM X11 extension.

Specifically, Blender's executable complains (in the remote machine terminal) with: `error code: 159`, `request code: 143`, `minor code: 34`, `error text: 159` and finally concludes with:

> Xlib:  extension "MIT-SHM" missing on display "localhost:10.0".

After this, the X11 window on the local machine remains open, as if the software runs without problems but displays nothing of Blender's GUI.

At the same time, as the mouse gets dragged along the local X11 window, the remote terminal still produces `XLib: extension "MIT-SHM"...` errors.

I have tried to find out more information about working with the MIT-SHM (installing, configuring, enabling / disabling, etc) but apart from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT-SHM), [this](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/xextproto/shm.html) and [this passing reference](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml#heading7) I have not had much luck.

While I am still working on this, I would appreciate anyone's help with the MIT-SHM as I suspect that Blender is not the only piece of software that might make use of it. It seems like a cool X11 feature but I do not think that I have full control over it on my Ubuntu bionic 18.04 that runs on the server of my setup.

1. How can I enable the MIT-SHM so that it shows up in the `xdpyinfo` listing?
2. Is there a specific set of libraries I should have installed for it to fully work?
3. Is there anything else that is implied by its use? (For example, do I need any extra ports enabled for this functionality to work?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use MIT-SHM from a remote X11 client.

Just think about its acronym: SHM = shared memory. If the client and the server are running on different machines, that cannot share memory.

That extension is supposed to speed up X11 requests which are transferring a lot of data by using the SySV shared memory API instead of writing it through a socket (eg. `XPutImage` -> `XShmPutImage`). Its benefits on modern computers are discutable IMHO.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about something going on with regards to the client but the message is generated on the remote server side and it reports that the extension is missing on display ``localhost:10.0``. My understanding is that this MIT-SHM is something that goes on between Blender and X11 at server side. X11 clients are pretty "thin". All they do is exchange messages and render patches that the server sends. What would your recommendation be for enabling it on a system? I understand it might not be the best thing ever.

Comment: You don't believe me, right? Let's give it another try: when you're forwarding your local display over ssh, the Xorg running on the local display (on the ssh client) is the X11 server and the program running on the remove machine (blender, on the ssh server) is the X11 client. Since they're running on separate machines, they **cannot share memory**, and they cannot use MIT-SHM. Forcing the X11 *server* to tell that it supports MIT-SHM will not help -- we're not in Wile E. Coyote vs. RoadRunner where simply drawing a tunner entrance on the mountain side will cause a train to come through it.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped and also led me to [this citation](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/trouble.php#head-23) which resolves the whole thing. Is it possible to turn off the use of the MIT-SHM on a per session basis or can it safely be assumed that if this fails then it is impossible to get Blender running in a setup like this?

Comment: "Its benefits on modern computers are discutable IMHO." I tested it and it's about 250,000 times faster(!) 1000 screenshots take about 7 seconds without it or 0.03 seconds with it

Comment: Never mind, I think I was using it wrong so that may or may not be true

Comment: It's actually only 300ish times faster, if I've done it right this time